# to prove that Inf$(B) \sqsubseteq $ Inf$(A)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

In a poset $(P, \sqsubseteq)$, and $A \subseteq B \subseteq P$. Also Infimum$(A)$ and Infimum$(B)$ exists.

I need to prove that Inf$(B) \sqsubseteq $ Inf$(A)$.

My Attempt.

Considered $x \in A$, it means it is also there in $B$

So Inf$(A) \sqsubseteq x $, similarly Inf$(B) \sqsubseteq x $

But I am not able to conclude Inf$(B) \sqsubseteq $ Inf$(A)$

Does anybody have a hint.

[Edit]- My understanding is  Inf$(A)$ is the lower bound for all elements of $A$

And similarly Inf$(B)$ is the lower bound for all elements of $B$

So from this I can conclude Inf$(B) \sqsubseteq $ Inf$(A)$ but How do I know that Inf$(A) \in A$, It can be outside of the A as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that $\operatorname{inf}(B)$ is a lower bound for $A$, and conclude your result from the definition of $\operatorname{inf}(A)$.

Comment: So you mean should I proceed with $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$, Showing that Inf$(A \cup B)$ is the lower bound of  Inf$(A \cap B)$. Is it fine to treat subsets as in words of union and intersection.

Comment: I think just dealing with the case where $A\subset B$ is fine, since ultimately if you show what you're proposing, that will follow from the $A\subset B$ case since $A\cap B \subset A\cup B$.  But that could also work if you need to use it.  Also, just make sure you're saying "a" lower bound, since in general you'll have more than a single lower bound for a subset.

Comment: Inf$(A)$ is the lower bound for all elements of $A$

And similarly Inf$(B)$ is the lower bound for all elements of $B$

So from this I can conclude Inf$(B) \sqsubseteq $ Inf$(A)$ but How do I know that Inf$(A) \in A$, It can be outside of the A as well.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't need to be in $A$.  Why do you want it to be?

Comment: Ok, So now I have framed the proof as : $ \qquad $ For $x \in A$ we have  Inf $A \sqsubseteq x $ $ \qquad $$ \qquad $ Also same $x$ is in $B$ so Inf $B \sqsubseteq x$. $ \qquad $  It means Inf $B$ is also the lower bound of $A$ . $ \qquad $ So for $A$ we have now 2 lower bounds but as per the def. $ \qquad $Inf $A$ will always be the greatest lower bounds $ \qquad $i.e. Inf $B \sqsubseteq $ Inf $A$   $\qquad$ Does this looks what you tried to explain me.

Comment: Yep, that looks good to me, though make sure you say "**a** lower bound of $A$"